# Open file directly after grep

Tags: linux, grep

I'm getting an issue on piping in linux,

```
ls | grep feedback
```

I have an alias for xdg-open which is open, how can do to make the filename from grep goes directly to open

this is not working

```
ls | grep feedback | open
```

Comment: Wouldn't `open *feedback*` be enough, actually?

Answer (score 5):

[xargs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) *builds and execute command lines from standard input*.

The syntax is simple:

```
ls | grep feeback | xargs open
```

This will not work if the file name contains a space. For example, for a file called `foo bar`:

```
ls | grep foo | xargs open
```

The above would attempt to open a file called `foo` and then a file called `bar`, since the space usually separates arguments.

In this case, you can use quotes to delimit the filename:

```
ls | grep foo | xargs -I '{}' open '{}'
```

However, this approach may fail if the filename contains spaces.

---

Another option would be using [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find), which avoids pipes altogether:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name '*foo*' -exec open '{}' \;
```

Here, `-maxdepth 1` makes find search only in the current directory (i.e., not including subdirectories), `-name '*foo*'` searches for files containing the string **foo** in their name and `-exec open {} \;`, replacing `{}` with the filename that has been found. find will deal automatically with special characters.

---

Through [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html), a similar result can be achieved:

```
open "$(ls | grep feedback)"
```

This will work, even if the file contains spaces.

Comment: Caveat when the file names contains spaces. I added that to your answer. If you think the change is too radical, feel free to roll back.